# Given 3 numbers N , L and R. Print 'yes' if N is between L and R else print 'no'

Tags: javascript

Given 3 numbers N , L and R. Print 'yes' if N is between L and R else print 'no'.
Sample Testcase :
INPUT
3
2 6
OUTPUT
yes

How to solve this problem using javascript, I can't even understand the question,So please help me to solve this....

Comment: In the given example N=3, L (left) = 2, and R (right) = 6. Is N between L and R is asking you "is the number 3 between the numbers 2 and 6?" Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4):

`N` is between `L` and `R` meaning `if (N > L && N < R){}` so in your example `(3, 2, 6) => N = 3, L = 2 and R = 6` so 3 is in between 2 and 6.

```js
const check = (N, L, R) => {
  if (N > L && N < R) return "yes";
  return "no";
}

console.log(check(3,2,6));
```

Comment: Depending on the interpretation of "between", of course. Arguably, this is not inclusive of L and R.

Comment: yes exactly my bad

Answer (score 1):

Those letters are supposed to be variables which contain a given number value. You want to check and see if the value in N is greater than the value in L but less than the value in R. For instance,

```
let L = 2
let N = 3
let R = 6

if (N > L && N < R) {
    console.log("Yes")}
else {
    console.log("No")}
```

So you're printing "yes" if 3 is greater than 2 AND less than 6, and you're printing "no" if it's not. And, of course, the only reason it would ever print "No" instead of "Yes" would be if your N variable contained a different number outside the range of the values in your other variables. For instance, if you changed the value in your N variable to contain the number 7 it would print "No."